# is there an R function for reversing the signs of the contents of a numeric vector?

Tags: r

is there a function in R that could turn, for example, 
'''
c(1,5,-15,23,-4)
'''
into
'''
c(-1,-5,15,-23,4
'''
? Any help would me much appreciated. It seems simple enough but I haven't found a simple solution yet. Note I am a beginner. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We can multiply by `-1` to change the sign

```
-1 * v1
#[1]  -1  -5  15 -23   4
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(1,5,-15,23,-4)
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is just to precede the value or vector of values with `-`

```
v1 <- c(1,5,-15,23,-4)
-v1
```

Returns

```
# [1]  -1  -5  15 -23   4
```

Comment: excellent - if you feel this answers your question please be sure to click the accept button!